# String index out of range, solution is working fine

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to change all the characters to the symbol "#" except the last 4. The error I get:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   
File "tests.py", line 16, in
> <module>
>     r = maskify(cc)   File "/workspace/default/solution.py", line 19, in maskify
>     n[i] = c[i]   IndexError: string index out of range
```

The code

```
c = "3656013700"
cc = list(c)
a = (len(cc)-1) - 4
b = []

def maskify(cc):
    n = list(len(cc) * "#")
    while len(cc) <= 4:
        return str(cc)
        break
    else:
        for i in range(len(cc)):
            if i <= a:
                n[i] = n[i]
            else:
                n[i] = c[i]  
    b = "".join([str(i) for i in n])
    return b

maskify(cc)
```

Comment: Why not just return `"#"*(len(cc) - 4) + cc[-4:]`?

Comment: If the goal is to mask the original `c`, you can use string repeat (actually an overload of multiplication) and slicing. `"#" * (len(c) - 4) + c[-4:]`. The multiplication expands the "#" the number of times needed and the slice takes the last 4 characters.

Comment: As side notes: `while len(cc) <= 4:` should be `if ...`, there is no loop here. `n[i] = n[i]` does nothing, so don't write it. You pass your function a list, but your function depends on global variables calculated from this list outside of the function. Give your variables sensible names: a, b, c, cc, n just mean nothing, make the code hard to read and the coding error prone.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you're complicating it. As @blorgon has already pointed it out, you can directly return it in one line. Further simplifying it, you don't need even need to convert the string into a list. Just directly pass the string as argument.

```
c = "3656013700"

def maskify(c):
    return (len(c) - 4) * "#" + c[-4:]

print(maskify(c))
```

If this is not what you're trying to achieve, your question is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

You are going through a complicated route. Here is another approach:

```
c = "3656013700"
def maskify(cc):
    return cc.replace(cc[:-4], '#'*(len(cc)-4))
print (maskify(c))
```

Output:

```
######3700
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go with the iterative approach you can simplify the code substantially:

```
def maskify(c):
    # Check if lenght of string is 4 or less
    if len(c) <= 4:
        return c

    else:
        # string into a list
        cc = list(c)
        # Iterate over the list - 4 last items
        for i in range(len(c)-4):
            cc[i] = "#"

        return "".join(cc)

s = "3656013700"

s = maskify(s)
print(s)
```